# React : How to use context and prevent a re render from each item in a list when action is dispatched and new data is received only for specific item?

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I have a list and render listItems. Each listitem fetches more data on button click. As long as Im making the api request (to fetch data) and store it inside my state inside listItem, everything works as expected. However, when Im using context and fetch data using context and not store it in my state but use the data returned from my reducer, what happens is: on button click of lets say listItem1, all listItems are being rerendered after fetching the data. That causes all listitems to display the same data. I am wondering if Im using context wrong or if its just the way it is and i cannot use context in this case (which seems not right).

```
const list = [{_id: "12345", name: "apples"}, {_id: "abcde", name: "pineapple"}, {_id: "54321", name: "bananas"}];
const detailsData = [
  {_id: "15", name: "apples", info:"info about an apple"}, 
  {_id: "abc", name: "pineapple",info:"info about a pineapple"}, 
  {_id: "1", name: "apples", info:"info about apple being green"}, 
  {_id: "2", name: "apples", info:"info about apple being round"}
];

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {list.map((listItem, index) => {
        return (
        <ListItem 
          name={listItem.name}
          key={index}
        />
        )
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

const ListItem = ({name}) => {
  const [showMore, setShowMore] = useState(false);
  const [details, setDetails] = useState([])
  
  const getDetails = async (name) => { //here it works fine as long as I make api call here + save details in component state
  new Promise((resolve) => { //fake api call
     const details = detailsData.filter(detail => detail.name === name);
      setDetails(details)
     })
  };

  const handleOnClick = async (name) => {
    setShowMore(!showMore)
    getDetails(name);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{name}</p>
      <button onClick={() => handleOnClick(name)}>see details</button>
      {
        showMore && <Details details={details}/>
      }
    </div>
  )
};

const Details = ({details}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {details.length > 0 ? details.map((detail, i) => { 
          return <p key={i}>{detail.info}</p>        
      }) : <p>No info here</p>}
    </div>
  )
};
```

if I however use context:

```
...

const ListItem = ({name}) => {
  const [showMore, setShowMore] = useState(false);
  const {state: {detailsFromContext}, getDetailsFromContext} = useContext(SearchContext);

  const handleOnClick = async (name) => {
    setShowMore(!showMore)
    getDetailsFromContext(name);
  }
...
  return (
      {
        ...
        showMore && <Details details={detailsFromContext}/>
        ...
      }
  )
};
```

ps.React memo wouldnt work here as every time i fetch new data it is being accepted by each listItem as 'new' data so it updates.

EDIT:

this is part of my context file:

```
export default (reducer, actions, defaultValue) => {
    const Context = createContext();
    const Provider = ({children}) => {
        const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, defaultValue)
        const boundActions = {};
        for (let key in actions) {
            boundActions[key] = actions[key](dispatch);
        }
        return (
            <Context.Provider value={{state, ...boundActions}}>
                {children}
            </Context.Provider>
        );
    };
    return { Context, Provider};
};

const searchReducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case'FETCH_DETAILS':
            return {...state, detailsFromContext: action.payload}
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

const getDetailsFromContext = dispatch => async (name) => {
    ...
        const detailsFromContext = await API.fetch(name);
        dispatch({type: 'FETCH_DETAILS', payload: detailsFromContext})
    ...
};

export const {Provider, Context} = createDataContext(
    searchReducer,
    {getDetailsFromContext},
    {
        detailsFromContext: [],
    }
)
```

Comment: `useContext` is for sharing a global state, I believe your component needs a local state. From the docs: React automatically re-renders all the children that use a particular context starting from the provider that receives a different value. https://react.dev/reference/react/useContext

Comment: so can I just then not use context in a case where im rendering a list of items?! or is there any other way to do it except using component level state instead?

Comment: `details` will be different for every `ListItem` instance, hence I believe a global state is a dead-end in this case.